# Access raw Eloquent mutated attribute value in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, accessor

Say I have a model `Foo` and I'm mutating an attribute getter, like so:

```
class Foo extends Model
{   
    protected $table = 'foo';

    public function getSomeBarAttribute($value)
    {
        return some_function($value);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the attribute's raw value, pre-mutation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The method you look for is [getOriginal](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal). To get the original value you might use:

```
$this->getOriginal('some_bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

In model is defined this var:

```
/**
 * The model attribute's original state.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $original = array();
```

It's protected so you should add a function to get original's values

(not tested)

Comment: Yeah I've essentially created a new function called `rawSomeBar` that returns `$this->attributes['some_bar']`.

Answer (score 0):

`getOriginal()` method return only db properties to *Array* type. So getAttributes and setAttributes, etc. values does have not including.

The *Array* returns  *[key => value]* that enough for new Eloquent instance. If you want to use GetAttributes that computed old properties, you can create new model instance before using getAttributes with Original Values

```php
$currentSomeBar = $foo->some_bar


$oldFoo = new Foo($foo->getOriginal());

$oldSomeBar = $oldFoo->some_bar;
```